# Passing in file path for xml file to use spring framework in android

Tags: java, android, xml, spring

I'm using the full spring framework in an android application*, and I need to pass in the path of an xml to the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext constructor, but I just can't find a way to do this since spring is not meant to take in android resources and just requires being able to find the file. I have tried many different ways to specify the path to any location in the project that I can think to put the xml in but I keep getting an IllegalStateException which can be traced back to this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [path/I/specified.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [path/I/specified.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

In a regular java program you can simply place the xml in the src directory, but here I'm having trouble understanding how spring would look for a file in the android app structure. If anyone knows how I might be able to get an absolute file path to pass in I would greatly appreciate it.

*I know this is not recommended but my application is based off an immensely complex program that uses it and I would love to be able to reuse some of the client code, which uses this framework in the depths of its bowels

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I ended up just placing my xml in the assets and then opening it in my code to get an input stream and just writing the file to the device and getting an absolute path from that. Code shown below.

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("my.xml");
File f = new File(getFilesDir(), "my.xml");
//helper method to write InputStream is to File f
String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
```